# Git Deleted all my changes before I committed them

Tags: git, commit

ok I'm a newb at Git, only been using it for a week, but everything has been fine so far.  I'm using GitHub Gui on mac.
Accessing one project (just me alone) but from 2 different macs (work and home)
So I get home, get latest version from the work commit. Work for a day, now its time to commit from home.
I click on sync, and quickly on changes to list my copious changes for the day.. 50+ files or so.
GitHub, pops up something about a conflict on a binary file (that I never touched, and shouldn't be in conflict as no one else is editing the project)
It gives me some option like you can't commit your changes until you fix and commit this conflict. I can't remember the second option, but I click commit.
It commits the conflicted binary file.. but then.... all my list of changes disappears from the changes window, and after loading up the project all the work for the day has gone...  !!!!!!!  it is back to looking like it did at the start of the day.
there is no record of a commit or any changes in github, except for the conflicted single binary file, and the commit from previous day at work.

What happened ? why were there no warnings ? Surely this cannot be how Git is supposed to behave when there is a conflict ?
Help please. is my work still somewhere ?

Comment: Git itself doesn't have a GUI to "click" on. Please specify what program you are using.

Comment: If you had called commit on local repo, then changes are safe there.   Other than that you are missing quite lot information for any one to help.  Provide more details on platform, git version, commit log etc.  A picture of your setup would help.

Comment: as mentioned, I am using GitHub gui, on a Mac. Project is a Unity3D project. I am in a Branch called 'Mobile' that no one else is using.

Comment: The 'Changes' window is empty. The 'History' window only shows previous commit, 1 day old, and the commit from the conflict resolution. I am still in the mobile branch.  There is no other info in the Gui apparent. I didn't get to commit any of my desired changes, as it said I had to commit the conflict first. when I did that, it deleted all of my changes at the same time.

Comment: Have you checked the actual content of the files you are worried about in your working tree? How about looking at the output of git log, or using gitk to check the visual state of things? If you committed your local changes as you described, of course they won't show up in a git status, git diff or other list of changes in a GUI -- because they've just been comitted.

Comment: git version 207 (latest as of writing this) I didn't get to commit any of my changes. Git popped up the warning before I could commit. Hence the panic that it deleted my files before I could commit any. For all my previous commits using GitHub Gui, you can just click in the History window, and it shows a list of all of the files that were committed. For this 'conflict' commit. Nothing is listed or mentioned of my 50+ files...  only the conflicted file. and the popup did say something about you have to commit the conflict first, before your other changes. I am not familiar with command line git

Comment: I checked the files in the project folder... all the work is reverted to the state of last check-in. new files are deleted. modified files have the mods removed. its like a full version revert. but I did not do / select anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and resolve the merge conflict and then sync again. Just find the spot where Git added to your binary file and delete the nasty stuff it added, plus whatever created the conflict. Then try to sync up again. It may be that Git just saved your recent changes in a local commit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That is kind of what I did in the first place that caused the loss of files. I don't understand why it would remove everything to previous commit state, even the non-conflicted files.   So I checked everything again, and there is nothing in conflict now. no nasty stuff like this >>>> this stuff was already sorted out the first time around when it warned me and I fixed and committed.  I tried syncing again.   nothing changed.  I think its all lost. I have no idea why. Cant even revert to a previous commit now... it wants to keep newer files and changes... sigh